# Why is Cocoapods 1.8.3 adding APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY to the Target Support xcconfig file?

Tags: cocoapods

We have used Cocoapods in our project for a long time. Ever since 1.8.3, it is adding `APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY` to one of our private pod's `Pods/Target Support Files/*/*.xcconfig` files, and this, in turn, is causing the build to fail.

As a workaround, we are removing that line, and things are working again.

I would like to fix this issue for good, and would like to know what precisely makes cocoapods add this flag, and what we need to make the project work again.

The pod in question is supposed to be used in extensions, this is true. It does contain conditional compilation (`#ifndef TARGET_IS_EXTENSION`) to exclude the code that should not go into extensions.

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it manually, you can do it automatically after a pod install with a `post_install` hook by adding the following to the bottom of your Podfile.

(Below is a template that might need a few tweaks depending on project)

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if target.name.include?(“CUSTOM_POD”). // or remove if statement to delete/set value for all pods
            config.build_settings.delete('APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY')
               //OR
            config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO' //or 'YES'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That is still just a weird cure to the symptoms. I would like to learn how the flag gets there. And if that is the correct thing. Because if it is, then we need to examine our code …

Comment: @below I agree, here is some additional reading for you about the [flag](https://miqu.me/blog/2016/11/28/app-extensions-xcode-and-cocoapods-omg/) and [another](https://davedelong.com/blog/2019/04/09/conditional-compilation-part-3/)